# ssh: suppress Banners of Jumphosts

Tags: ssh, banner, jumphost

Gday Everyone,

i am using ssh with jumphost(s).

```
ssh -J zone1-jumphost zone2-target
```

or .ssh/config:

```
HOST zone1-* zone2-* !zone1-jumphost
   ProxyJump zone1-jumphost
```

All servers (jumphost(s) and target) are configured to print out an issue message like "Authorized access only!".
I can suppress the target servers message with the option '-q'.

But how can i suppress the message created by the jumphost(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an empty file on the target server in your users home directory called `~/.hushlogin` and it will stop the message of the day from displaying.

Just connect and run `touch ~/.hushlogin` and the next time you log in it should be suppressed.

Comment: It does not really solves my problem. It suppresses the /etc/motd, but not the /etc/issue, and does not suppress anything coming from the jumphost.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case try running `ssh -o loglevel=ERROR`  on your local host before connecting.

Comment: As before this also has no effect to the output coming from the jumpserver. It works only for the target's output.

Comment: Understood. I just mocked this up in my lab and I was able to get it working. Add this line to the top of your ~/.ssh/config file on your local machine:

    `LogLevel ERROR`

Then run your ssh command `ssh -J jump-server remote-server`